# What PCRE will deliver a sub-string if present, else null?

Tags: regex, pcre

What regex that includes X as a subexpression will, when replaced by $1, yield the first match with X, or if there's none, null (i.e. empty string)?

For example, with X == "there"

```
<?php
echo '1: '.preg_replace(???, '$1','hello there dolly')."\n"; // -> 'there'
echo '2: '.preg_replace(???, '$1','hello dolly')."\n"      ; // -> ''
?>
```

Please note that what I'm seeking is an answer to the question, not just to this one example.

Comment: I don't know about null, but you can easily write a regex with a capture group that gives you an empty string in the second case.

Comment: @Oli, by null I meant null string i.e. empty string. And what is this easily written regex, please?

Comment: @ChrisJJ In your case the regex would be: `(there)`

Comment: @Lucas, replacing with $1 leaves the rest of the input string. I shall clarify my question.

Comment: You only need to make the group optional: see this example: http://regex101.com/r/iO5iA5/1

Comment: @Casimir: that's good enough to post as answer. (Consider using `*` instead of `+`, using `.` rather than `\w` and adding `^` and `$`. Just to make it a bit more robust.)

Comment: @Casimir, thanks, but that doesn't work in other cases e.g. #. http://regex101.com/r/iO5iA5/2

Comment: It's only the way to do it, I don't know what you are trying to do, you must adapt it to fit your real requirements (that nobody knows)

Comment: @Casimir, I was hoping for a general solution, but I guess there is none. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucas, Agreed, but "there" was just an example. I'm looking for a solution for any input string.

Comment: @Casimir, "You only need to make the group optional: see this example: regex101.com/r/iO5iA5/1 " Note that your solution does not only make the group optional. It also requires a space. If I remove it, the match fails regex101.com/r/wO6vI2/1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.*?(X).*|.*
```

e.g.

```
<?php
echo '1: '.preg_replace('~.*?(there).*|.*~', '$1','hello there dolly')."\n"; // -> 'there'
echo '2: '.preg_replace('~.*?(there).*|.*~', '$1','hello dolly')."\n"      ; // -> ''
?>
```

Fuller tests here https://regex101.com/r/YLRTfZ/3/tests .

Answer (score 2):

If you make the capture optional, you'll get a blank if there's no match:

```
(?<=hello )(\w+)?(?= dolly)
```

Note: I have assumed you to match a wordbetween "hello" and "dolly". Adjust the regex to suit.

Comment: Bohemian, that solves for the given example case, but not for a large majority of cases covered by the question. Here's a solution for all cases covered by the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/40995445/896451

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\w*` for zero or more in the middle match:

```
^hello\s(\w*)\s?dolly
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gE3fS6/2)

If you want to match everything in between (like bookends) you can make the matching group optional:

```
^hello\s(.*)?\bdolly
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/gE3fS6/5)

Comment: Dawg, that solves for the given example case, but not for a large majority of cases covered by the question. Here's a solution for all cases covered by the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/40995445/896451

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, it's probably easiest check for a failed match in whatever language you are calling PCRE from.

In Perl itself, for instance, a failed match does not update the capture variables. For this reason, usually you want to check the success or failure of a match: `print "$1\n" if /(there)/`. But you can use this behavior to your advantage:

```
{ # Start a new scope so that $1 is null.
  /(there)/; # Or whatever pattern you are searching for
  print "$1\n"; # Print whether or not the string matched
}
```

You might be able do it in a regex *if* you know something more about the string. A commenter suggested:

> You only need to make the group optional: see this example: [regex101.com/r/iO5iA5/1](http://regex101.com/r/iO5iA5/1) –  Casimir et Hippolyte

As you noted, that regex assumes the subpattern is surrounded by spaces. If the string you are matching doesn't have spaces to anchor the capturing group, it will fail. If you remove all anchors, the optional group will match each null string, which can produce some [strange results](http://regex101.com/r/zL0tC9/5).

In summary, if you know something about the structure of the string, you can use an optional capturing group. If you just want to check if a string contains a particular pattern (and return null if not) use the language that wraps PCRE.

Comment: Yes I can test success in the outer language but I was hoping for a transportable PCRE-only solution. I'm reading your answer as None. Thanks. That saves me further time searching!